# HTML/PHP Checkbox Values Only Return "On"

Tags: php, html, forms, email, checkbox

Brand new to both HTML and PHP so forgive me for what is probably an elementary question.

This code is for a skeletal HTML/PHP form that emails some user input. I've been searching for many hours on a fix for this, but I haven't been able to get a solution.

I'm trying to find a way to store the actual strings of the checkbox values (i.e. First, Second) instead of having the php code return "On" boolean values for either checkbox when they're checked.

Here's the relevant code below:

Form:

```
<form action="formhandle.php" method="post">

<div class="row">
    <label>Choose</label>
    <input name="samplecheck[]" type="checkbox" value="First"><label>Checkbox 1</label>
    <input name="samplecheck[]" type="checkbox" value="Second"><label>Checkbox 2</label>
</div>

</form>
```

Handler method 1:

```
$value = $_POST['samplecheck'];

for($i=0; $i < count($value); $i++){
    $box .= "Checked : " . $value[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Handler method 2:

```
foreach($_POST['samplecheck'] as $value) {
    $box .= "Checked: $value \n";
}
```

I know there's limited validation but that's not my concern right now. Both handling methods "work" in that they properly recognize when a checkbox value is "On" or "Off", but they only will ever return "On", and I have no idea how to return the actual string of the value.

In either case, if both checkboxes are checked, I'll get this output for $box :

Checked : On
Checked : On

What am I doing wrong? Is it only ever supposed to return On? If so, how am I supposed to tell each array entry apart?

Comment: Can you please clarify this: **but they only will ever return "On"** ?

Comment: Like I said in the question description, the $value variable stores "On" when a checkbox is checked, rather than the actual value *string* names (First, Second).

Comment: Also to clarify, the output is "on", all lowercase, not "On". My mistake.

Comment: I've tested the code and it works, it outputs First, Second. Make sure you add a submit button, otherwise you're not posting anything.

Comment: `on` is the value that is send for checked ckeckboxes that _don’t_ have a `value` attribute set. Check your HTML code for errors – most likely you have written something wrong in there, so that the `value` attribute is not recognized by the parser. It is always a good idea to validate your HTML – https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: And btw., your `label` elements are pointless, since they are not “connected” to the input fields – you need to set the `for` attribute that contains the value of the `id` of the corresponding input field (or have the `label` wrapped around the `input`.) And `<label>Choose</label>` makes no sense at all – don’t misuse labels to mark up just random text.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the insight about checking for errors. I'll get back once I clean up the code. The label elements were attached to id's but I removed them for fear that they were causing this value difficulty.

Comment: @CBroe I found the problem ... it was because my checkbox was sharing the same row as a radio. I suppose there's a whole other issue involved if I ever wanted to keep the radio and checkbox in-line with eachother, but for now this will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to CBoe:

" `on` is the value that is send for checked checkboxes that don’t have a value attribute set. Check your HTML code for errors – most likely you have written something wrong in there, so that the value attribute is not recognized by the parser. It is always a good idea to validate your HTML – validator.w3.org "

In my case, and this is my fault for not including a more full code snippet, my checkboxes were sharing the same row as my radio, and simply placing them into separate rows allowed the checkbox value to function properly:

Bad code :

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
            <label>Choose</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rad_choices" value="Red" id="rad_id1"><label for="rad_id1">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rad_choices" value="Blue" id="rad_id2"><label for="rad_id2">Radio 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
            <label>Choose</label>
            <input name="samplecheck[]" type="checkbox" value="First" id="check_id1"><label for="check_id1">Checkbox 1</label>
            <input name="samplecheck[]" type="checkbox" value="Second" id="check_id2"><label for="check_id2">Checkbox 2</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Good code :

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
            <label>Choose</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rad_choices" value="Red" id="rad_id1"><label for="rad_id1">Radio 1</label>
            <input type="radio" name="rad_choices" value="Blue" id="rad_id2"><label for="rad_id2">Radio 2</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
            <label>Choose</label>
            <input name="samplecheck[]" type="checkbox" value="First" id="check_id1"><label for="check_id1">Checkbox 1</label>
            <input name="samplecheck[]" type="checkbox" value="Second" id="check_id2"><label for="check_id2">Checkbox 2</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Why they can't be placed in the same row, I don't know. This might be due to another problem with my code that I'm failing to see, but this is an adequate solution for my purposes. For anyone with similar purposes, simply check your code for anything that would be affecting its ability to recognize or store the checkbox values.

Answer (score 2):

When I tested your example on my server I receive the expected values. So I will provide you my code so you can edit it to suit your needs

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <label>Choose</label>
    <input name="samplecheck[]" type="checkbox" value="First"><label>Checkbox 1</label>
    <input name="samplecheck[]" type="checkbox" value="Second"><label>Checkbox 2</label>
</div>
<input type='submit'>
</form>

<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $box = '';
    foreach($_POST['samplecheck'] as &$value) {
        $box .= "Checked: $value \n";
    }
    echo $box;
}
?>
```

**"I receive the expected values" which values did you receive ? –  Pedro Lobito"**

To answer this question.

If I do not select any checkbox, I receive no output.

If I select the "First" checkbox i receive the text

> Checked: First

If I select the "Second" checkbox i receive the text

> Checked: Second

If I select the "Second" checkbox and if I select the "First" checkbox I receive the text

> Checked: First Checked: Second

Comment: **"I receive the expected values"** which values did you receive ?

Comment: I used your php code but still received an echo output of "Checked: on Checked: on". Any idea as to what's going on here?

Comment: Unfortunately this can not be replicated based on the code you have provided. Please feel free to paste my code in at http://phpfiddle.org/ in the codespace section.

Comment: @Pedro Lobito That depends on which checkbox you check. If none, none, if the first one, First, if the second one Second, if both, both. IE: The expected values

Comment: @jesse , Ok, I've tested the code and I can also confirm that it works.